# T-SQL to find a node within a dynamic XML structure

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, xquery

I would like to know what is the correct way to write a T-SQL query to return either the value or attribute of a node from a dynamic (multilevel) XML structure?

For example, if the XML looked like this:

```
<xml>
  <a>
    <b>1</b>
    <c>
      <node attrib="ant">2</node>
    </c>
  </a>
  <a>
    <node attrib="bird">3</node>
  </a>
  <a>
    <b>
      <c>
        <node attrib="cat">4</node>
      </c>
    </b>
  </a>
</xml>
```

What is the correct query to return the values and/or the attributes for *node*? As shown in this example, *node* can be at any level...

I've tried something like this (without success):

```
SELECT
  node.value('node[1]', 'varchar(50)') AS node
  node.value('(node/@attrib)[1]', 'varchar(50)') AS attrib
FROM
  xml.nodes('//xml/*') AS xml(node)
```

**EDIT:**
Thanks StuartLC for the answer below...

Based on the help below, here is a working example which also contains namespaces:

```
DECLARE @xml XML;
SET @xml = '
<xml xmlns:abc="xyz">
    <a>
        <b>1</b>
        <c>
            <abc:node attrib="ant">2</abc:node>
        </c>
    </a>
    <a>
        <abc:node attrib="bird">3</abc:node>
    </a>
    <a>
        <b>
            <c>
                <abc:node attrib="cat">4</abc:node>
            </c>
        </b>
    </a>
</xml>';

;WITH XMLNAMESPACES('xyz' AS ns)
SELECT
    Nodes.node.value('.', 'varchar(50)') AS node,
    Nodes.node.value('(./@attrib)[1]', 'varchar(50)') AS attrib
FROM
    @xml.nodes('//ns:node') AS Nodes(node);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like so:

```
SELECT
  Nodes.node.value('.', 'varchar(50)') AS node,
  Nodes.node.value('(./@attrib)[1]', 'varchar(50)') AS attrib
FROM
  @xml.nodes('//node') AS Nodes(node);
```

Because it seems that your `node` elements can sit at any place in your `xml` document, the `//` is used to search all elements. Once each `node` is found, `current()` or just `.` can be used to access this node.

[SqlFiddle here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/68b32/366)

**Edit**: For parsing an `xml` column off a table (as opposed to an Xml @variable):

```
 SELECT
  Nodes.node.value('.', 'varchar(50)') AS node,
  Nodes.node.value('(./@attrib)[1]', 'varchar(50)') AS attrib
FROM
    [TableWithXmlColumn] xyz
    cross apply xyz.XmlCol.nodes('//node') as Nodes(node);
```

Comment: Thanks. For a "simple" structure your query works great! :)

If I complicate things a little more by adding in a namespace, how would the code look then?

For example:
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/68b32/373

Answer (score 2):

If you want the values in the same column you can use something like this:

```
select T.X.value('.', 'varchar(50)')
from @XML.nodes('//*/text(), //@*') as T(X)
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d41d8/28158)